# RadioButton on ASCX no value on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, updatepanel, ascx

I seem to have hit a snag using radiobuttons on a usercontrol(ascx) and reading their value at postback.

I created a control that has a standard yes / no / not applicable functionality

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelYesNoSelector" runat="server">   
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonYes" runat="server" Text="Ja"/>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonNo" runat="server" Text="Nee"/>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonNotApplicable" runat="server" Text="Niet van toepassing"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

The group is set during PreRender in code behind, to keep all buttons from being selectable at the same time.

The control is used on an updatepanel.

When I hit save (button on the parent page) and try to read the value of the control through my GetValue() method, the selection remains nothing.

Does anyone have an idea as to why my values aren't available serverside?
I've been looking for quite a while and I'm coming up empty

We're also using telerik, which COULD jumble up the postback I guess

help?

Comment: Use your eyeballs to look through the Request.Form collection for something resembling the RadioButton return value.  dealing with an ASCX changes the naming of each control.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to call the aspx who is instancied ?